# How to update properties with functions within a foreach loop?

Tags: php, xml, function, properties, parameters

I would like to change some properties of an object in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($object->array as $element) {
    $element['foo'] = $new_foo;
    $element['bar'] = $new_bar;
}
```

How should I do this with a function? Or else how could I do this with object-oriented approach? My code doesn't work, as it only changes the value of the `$handle` variable within the function:

```
function change_attribute(&$handle, $new_value) {
    $handle = $new_value;
}

foreach ($object->array as $element) {
    change_attribute($element['foo'], $new_foo);
    change_attribute($element['bar'], $new_bar);
}
```

---

## The actual code

```
foreach ($xml->database[0]->table as $table) {
    $table->column[1]['name'] = 'new value';
}
```

It succesfully updates the `$xml` object without referencing the array element (that would cause a fatal error). Why can't I do the same with this function?

```
function change_attribute(&$handle, $old, $new) {
    if ($handle == $old) {
        $handle = $new;
    }
}

foreach ($xml->database[0]->table as $table) {
    change_attribute($table->column[1]['name'], 'old value', 'new value');
}
```

### The `$xml` object

```
php > var_dump($xml->database[0]->table);
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(7) "objects"
  }
  ["column"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(4)
    [1]=>
    string(1)
    [2]=>
    string(17)
    [3]=>
    string(17)
    [4]=>
    string(1949)
  }
}
```

This is identical to `var_dump($xml->database[0]->table[0])` except the later is `object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (2)`.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (2) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "old value"
  }
  [0]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to pass the object to the function and not the class property. Unfortunately the later must be hard-coded in the function:

```
function change_column_name(&$table, $index, $old, $new) {
    if ($table->column[$index]['name'] == $old) {
        $table->column[$index]['name'] = $new;
    }
}

foreach ($xml->database[0]->table as $table) {
    change_column_name($table, 1, 'old value', 'new value');
}
```

[George Brighton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18861213/868052) is right concerning arrays, but `SimpleXMLElement` objects cannot be used the same way, likely because they are objects embed in objects as class properties.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `$element` a reference using `&`, i.e.

```
foreach ($object->array as &$element) {...}
```

Without it, you're manipulating a copy of `$object->array` rather than the array itself. Have a look at the PHP docs on [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php).

Comment: another way would be to have the function return the modified array and assign it to the `$object` variable that called the function in the first place, thus replacing its original contents. It's more expensive than your answer, but it works.

Comment: PHP has references... we may as well use them :)

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton I did the same before you suggested, as it is written in the [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in example #10, but that gave me `Fatal error:  An iterator cannot be used with foreach by reference`. The problem might be somewhere else in my code, today I'm going to check it.

Comment: @Gergő in the meantime, you might as well use my suggestion then haha. No seriously, it's expensive. Use it as last-resort or time-saver only.

Comment: @Gergő Not sure why that's happening. Have a look at this example: http://pastebin.com/iePMvxjD. Could you add the output of `var_dump($object->array);` to your question?

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton The code you pasted doesn't update the object without using the reference, while the actual code I'm using does, so I updated my question with the details. I see that iterating through a `SimpleXMLElement` is more complicated than through a simple array which is a property. 

@victorantunes Or I might end up copy-pasting the code from the function and changing the parameters by hand as plan C.